# How to add attributes to an element using an object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add an element some attributes like `href`, `download`

Take a look at the code below

```
var el = document.createElement('a');
el.href = '..'
el.download  = 'foo.mp3'
```

The above works, but it seems to me like `el` is being treated as a js `Object` and `.href`, `.download` are the properties.

As in:

```
Person = {};
Person.name = 'foo'
Person.age  = 25
```

In the above example, I can simply do the following and it will be the same as above:

```
Person = {name: 'foo', age: 25}
```

But it doesn't work for the `el`, ex:

```
el = {href: '..', download: 'foo.mp3'}
```

So, why doesn't it work and what am I doing wrong? if any.

Comment: `document.createElement()` creates/returns an [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) representing a node of the DOM tree which has tons of properties and methods. Your last example creates an Object with two properties, `href` and `download`, in no way suitable to be appended to the DOM tree. (Also, `el` *is* treated like an Object, because that's what it is. Just not an empty one.)

Comment: HTML Element !== Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`href` and `download` aren't just regular properties. They are getter / setter pairs that reflect the changes you make to them to the DOM. An example would be:

```
  let obj = {
    get prop() { console.log("property retrieved"); },
    set prop(v) { console.log("property set to " + v); },
  };

  obj.prop = "test"; // this calls the setter
  obj = { prop: "test" }; // this does not trigger the setter, it replaces the object as a whole
```

Comment: This is interesting. So, what is the use of the getter. I have seen these many times but never knew till today what they do

Answer (score 2):

Object are things which are modified not reassignment. You are right `el` is an object. When you change it with `=` it will not then refer to the element.

You can use `for..in` loop.

```
let obj = {href: '..', download: 'foo.mp3'};
for(let k in obj){
   el[k] = obj[k]
}
```

See the working example below.

```js
var el = document.createElement('div');
let obj = {className:'red', id:'big', innerHTML:'Text'};
for(let k in obj){
  el[k] = obj[k]
}
document.body.appendChild(el)
```

```css
.red{
  color:red;
}
#big{
  font-size:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The = will overwrite the variable or set it.
In your case, your overwriting the variable instead of changing it's attributes.

```
 el = {href: '..', download: 'foo.mp3'}
```

To change its attributes, check out the solution by maheer.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `document.createElement` them you can must be use elment.setAttribute to define attributes values, ex:

```
let el = document.createElement('a');
el.setAttribute("href","yor_ref");
...
```